# Can VS Code editor workspace files specify default starting directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to have a single place to store all my Visual Studio Code editor workspace files.  I know I can use `Workspaces: Save Workspace As` to save the workspace file wherever I want, however, when I open a terminal the current working directory is the location where the workspace file is stored.  I want to be able to specify (for each individual workspace) what the starting directory should be.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that by default the `path` element of the `-workspace` file is stored relative to the workspace file.  By changing that to store the absolute path (which, I understand may not be the solution in all cases), it does work as I was intending.